# If statement and Boolean questions?

Tags: java

I cant seem to figure out why my code will run the way I see it running. What i am missing?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class EvenOdd {

    public static boolean isEven(int number) {
        if(number %2 == 0){
          System.out.println("Given number is even.");
         return true;    
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Given number is odd.");
         }
        return false;
              }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = 0;
    Scanner scanner =new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter any number Even or ODD");
      number = scanner.nextInt();

  }
}
```

I expect to see even or odd depending on the number the user puts in?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Java starts. Java runs your main method. Java creates a new variable, named `number`. Its value is 0.. A new scanner is made. The text 'Enter any number Even or ODD' is printed. A number is retrieved from the keyboard.

And then your program ends.

Yes, your code has an `isEven` method, but nothing calls it. You'd have to actually call the `isEven` method in your main, for example with:

```
isEven(number);
```

as final line in your main method.

Comment: Per this Answer’s advice, see example [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/ay66cC).

Answer (score 1):

You never ran your `isEven(int)` method. Try calling the method in your main class by writing `isEven(int)`.

Answer (score -1):

You missed the call of the `isEven` method in main method

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class EvenOdd {

    public static boolean isEven(int number) {
        if (number % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Given number is even.");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Given number is odd.");
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int number = 0;
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter any number Even or ODD");
            number = scanner.nextInt();

            boolean isEven = isEven(number);

            System.out.println(isEven);

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Handle Exception " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Handle the exception if other than number given as an input.

Comment: you can have finally block and close the scanner over there if any exception arises

Comment: Never close the stdin input stream. Keep it open.

Comment: Have a read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24573084/why-we-should-i-close-a-java-util-scanner-variable

Comment: I rather go with Oracle docs: 'The "standard" input stream. This stream is already open and ready to supply input data. Typically this stream corresponds to keyboard input or another input source specified by the host environment or user.'
So you didn't aquire it but the "host environment or user". And so you shouldn't close it. If you do you break an OS("host environment") resource for good - with all bad effects that may have.

Comment: FWIW: do you also close System.err and System.out? Hopefully you don't. And if you don't: you should treat System.in the same way.

Comment: @Ros5292 as others have mentioned, do not close System.in. It's annoying that various linting tools whinge about this, but the problem lies with linters that insist filterstreams need closing. In various situations they don't.

Comment: Happy to update my answer by removing `scanner.close();`